# What is the best way to use GPS in a Android Service without drain the batery? Is there a good library for this?

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

I want to consult the user's location when the application is closed or in background to send message Push. What's the best way for not drain battery. Is there a good library for this?

Answer (score 1):

Google provides his Location Services API which has a lot of useful info. Here is a couple things to consider when using it https://www.toptal.com/android/android-performance-tips-tools#location-updates

Answer (score 0):

My friend `FusedLocationApi` will help you. Advantages of this : faster and efficient battery usage comparing to `Android's` `LocationProvider`.

First of all you must create a `STICKY_SERVICE` read service tutorial : [Android Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), and search for it. Then in your service connect your `FusedLocationApi` and get `Location` information when `Location` change . Then handle new location. Also there is different modes when you getting `Location` information, you can see below :

```
/* Information taken from : http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/fused-location-provider

    Priority                update interval      Battery drain per hour (%)     Accuracy
    HIGH_ACCURACY           5 seconds                   7.25%                   ~10 meters
    BALANCED_POWER          20 seconds                  0.6%                    ~40 meters
    NO_POWER                N/A                         small                   ~1 mile

*/
```

You can read this tutorial for beginners : [beginners-guide-location-android](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android) and update your question , what you tried and we will help you easily !